# how to save audio and get its full path ??

Tags: cordova

i want to record audio and then save the audio and get the full path or src of that Audio file

so , i have two questions :

1-  if i have used this code for first time to save file name as "blank.mp3"

then if i want to record a another file as previous file name "blank.mp3" it will replace old one by new one ?? or it will not save the new one and give me Error???

2- src variable will contain full path of that file??

3- in summary the below code will record and save audio file and get its full path??

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function fail(){});
}, false);

var gotFS = function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("blank.mp3",
        { create: true, exclusive: false }, //create if it does not exist
        function success(entry) {
            var src = entry.toURI();
            console.log(src); //logs blank.wav's path starting with file://
        },
        function fail() {}
    );
};
```

Comment: why no one help me??? always i have ask questions and no reply why???

Answer (score 0):

1. replace old one with no error. If you change exclusive to true, it would return error
2. Yes
3. It do nothing with recording, just create a file if not exists, and log the file url path